# Statrt newActivity from onChildClick of expandableListView

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working with `ExpandableListView` on Android. I have to call different activities by clicking on the child. Each child have to direct me to new activity. Please tell me how can I do that.

My code is somewhat like:

```
list.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ExpandableListAdapter adap = parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int gp = (int) adap.getGroupId(groupPosition);
        int cp = (int) adap.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (gp == 0) {
            switch (cp) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Test11.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Test12.class);
                }
            } else if (gp == 1) {
                switch (cp) {
                case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Test21.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Test22.class);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: what is the difficulty you are facing now?

Comment: when I click on child node the application stops unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

maybe I believe you are missing startActivity(),

```
list.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ExpandableListAdapter adap = parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int gp = (int) adap.getGroupId(groupPosition);
        int cp = (int) adap.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (gp == 0) {
            switch (cp) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Test11.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Test12.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else if (gp == 1) {
                switch (cp) {
                case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Test21.class);
               startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Test22.class);
               startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Error is "The application ExpandableView (package name) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Comment: in the log cat it gives a unhandled NullPointerException error.

Comment: more specific. in what line is it giving you null pointer. Try to show me that line here

Comment: when I click on the first child of first group. I am writing the complete error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity {package/package.classname}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: actually there is a problem int the setcontentview of test11 file... when you tell me I just checked and found my minor error. and the code you have given worked well.. :)

Comment: In general, when you get a an error message, you need to tell us the entire error. It's not that helpful to know that you just have a NullPointerException without giving the file, line number, and at least a partial backtrace. Just copy/paste from the console :)